# Gate potential wiith siesta/transiesta

Tags: siesta, transport

I want to study the effect of adding a gate to quantum transport device, the problem that i encounter is that in siesta manual there are two methods to do so, the first is "Geometry.Charge" and the second is "Geometry.Hartree" which gives no change in  transport properties. However, with `Geometry.Charge` i noticed a shift in fermi energy, but the problem is that with the code you can only precise the charge density not the dedired shift of Ef. So how can i know the charge to apply for the gate in order to have a defined shift value ?
My second question is about the position of gate, in the manual we find this code to apply a square gate:

```
square 1. eV # The lifting potential on the geometry
delta
1.0 1.0 1.0 Ang # The starting point of the square
2.0 0.5 0.2 Ang # The first spanning vector
0.0 2.5 0.2 Ang # The second spanning vector
```

**But there is no explanation regarding the details of each parameter, for example, the origin of the spanning vector.**

Thank you for you help in advance

Comment: `But there is no explanation regarding the details of each parameter, for example, the origin of the spanning vector..` I don't understand? The comments on the lines specify exactly what each parameter means? What is unclear in this regard?

Comment: thank you for your response i fixed the problem, but i got another question, if you don't mind. I want to know the gate potential value, since i'm using the geometry charge input, i'm comparing the Electrostatic potential values before and after. Now the problem is that, i can't extract data from nc file using sisl, how can i fix that ?

Comment: sisl automatically reads data from the `nc` files. And comparing the two might be difficult since their reference point is not the same...

Comment: Is there any way to know either the shift in Fermi energy after the gate application or the value of the gate bias ?

Comment: You can look at the potential profile between the geometry and the gate. That should give you a ramp, from this you can calculate the electric field etc. The fermi-energy shift can be done by comparing band-structures (before and after).

Comment: Since my gate is on the scattering region i don't have access to the band structure. For your suggestion about the potential profile, i'm not sure how to do that, is it by using the same ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc file ?  I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Ok, then do the DOS from tbtrans and compare. It all depends on how you apply the gate. So I can't answer that. You'll have to think what the gate does, and how it affects your system.

Comment: Ok then, i'll try the DOS, thanks

Comment: Dear nick, According to your paper "manipulating the voltage drop in graphene nanojunctions using a gate potential" gate should be applied to both scattering region and electrodes. Does it mean, we should include Geometry.Charge in electrode calculation ? If we put Geometry.Charge only in transport calculation input, will it be applied only to the scattering region ? In the Geometry.Charge parameters, there is plane with different configurations: delta, exp, gauss what is the difference between them and does plane means infinite plane ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, if the gate you are introducing is also present under the electrodes, then *you* should ensure that the same charge-distribution is changed in the electrode part as in the device part.
As the manual specifies, the different configurations are different shapes of the charge distribution profiles, yes, plane is infinite, by definition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have more questions if you don't mind:

Comment: I am attempting to simulate a single electron transistor. As you may know, the gate in this case is applied only to the scattering region. However, in your paper titled "Manipulating the voltage drop in graphene nanojunctions using a gate potential," you mentioned that if we do so, we will encounter incorrect boundary conditions.

Comment: I used the following code to apply the gate in the scattering region: %block Geometry.Charge
square 0.0007 charge # The lifting potential on the geometry
 delta
   4.914916     16.405063     14.291678  Ang # The starting point of the square
   4.914916     18.100628     14.291678  Ang # The first spanning vector
  18.173464     16.405063     14.291678  Ang # The second spanning vector
%endblock Geometry.Charge

Comment: However, I encountered the following error in Slurm: madelung: WARNING: Charged system, but not an atom or molecule.
madelung: WARNING: Energy correction terms cannot be applied.
madelung: WARNING: Continue only if you really know what you are doing.
I also received the following instruction: Geometric charge distributions:
   Finite delta-plane     adding  0.10000E-02 e divided in 1567 grid points

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found any explanation regarding these issues. Additionally, when I checked the region where the gate is applied by plotting ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc and TotalPotential.grid.nc with sisl, I found that the gate potential is present throughout the entire scattering region, even though I specified a smaller region in the input.

Could you please help me understand these errors and why the gate potential extends beyond the intended region?

Comment: You need to start thinking about how a charge in a unit-cell influences the potential all-around. And as I mentioned in the Manipulating ..., one needs to ensure that the gate does not interfere with the electrode potential, in that case one need not have a gate in the electrode region, but if the device gate _does_ interfere with the electrode potential, then you need to also have the gate there. Regarding madelung, that is well described in the manual or in litterature.

Comment: Dear nick, thank you for your guidance, it really helped me. I have another question if you don't mind, I used to copy .TSHS/. TSDE/. DM files from the closest bias to calculate the new one as indicated in the manual. Now I'm fixing the Source/Drain bias, and incrementaly changing the gate voltage, can i follow the same strategy to help the convergence ? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes. That should still be better.

Comment: Dear nick, thank you again, i still have two questions, the first one about the interface between scattering region and electrodes, i want to use a sort of tunnel junction between them, can i use buffer region for this ? my second question is about DFT+U, i'm trying to capture coloumb blockade effects, could it work using your siesta implementation of hubbard model ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MohamedAmine please ask follow-up questions in new posts, not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

> "But there is no explanation regarding the details of each parameter, for example, the origin of the spanning vector... "

Nick Papior's [comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10994/gate-potential-wiith-siesta-transiesta#comment23566_10994) implied that enough information was provided in the comments in the lines below:

```
square 1. eV    # The lifting potential on the geometry
delta
1.0 1.0 1.0 Ang # The starting point of the square
2.0 0.5 0.2 Ang # The first spanning vector
0.0 2.5 0.2 Ang # The second spanning vector
```

Although the "origin" of the first and second spanning vectors is not something that is explained explicitly in the comments, it seems that the OP was satisfied with this answer, as seen the first part of [this comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10994/gate-potential-wiith-siesta-transiesta#comment23588_10994) which was a response from the OP to Nick's first comment:

> "thank you for your response i fixed the problem"

All other questions that the OP asked in the comment section after the above part of the first comment by the OP, would have been more appropriately asked in separate posts on the site. **I apologize that I nor anyone else was able to catch this earlier, before all those questions got asked and in some cases answered in the comments section.**

Comment: I apologize for not asking for more questions. ;)